# Insert many based on upserting condition with Pymongo

Tags: pandas, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I am trying to find an efficient way to upload a Pandas DataFrame to a MongoDB collection with the following constraints:

- If the document is already existing, based on 2 unique document features (namely, 'business_id' and 'document_key'), overwrite
- If the document does not exist, based on the same 2 unique document features (namely, 'business_id' and 'document_key'), create one

I tried with:

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne

upserts=[ 
    UpdateOne(
        {"$and": [
            {'business_id': x['business_id']},
            {"document_key": x["document_key"]}
             ]
             }, 
        {'$setOnInsert': x}, 
        upsert=True
        ) 
    for x in dd.to_dict("records")
    ]

result = collection.bulk_write(upserts)
```

But it does not seem to be updating the document, nor behaving to the overwriting/new document creations policies described above.

How can I perform the insertion in line with the 2 illustrated bullet points?

Comment: it is important to know what is your mongod server version and if it is a sharded cluster since there is a difference on upsert behaviour starting from version 4.2

Comment: It is a serverless instance, thus mounting the latest version

Comment: the items in upserts need to be separated with ","  , what is the output from: for x in dd.to_dict("records") , you may need to add some comma  perhaps. to form [ UpdateOne(),UpdateOne(),UpdateOne() etc. ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want `$set` instead of `$setOnInsert`

> If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a
> document, then $setOnInsert assigns the specified values to the fields
> in the document. **If the update operation does not result in an insert,
> $setOnInsert does nothing.**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

Worked example using $set:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db['mycollection']

collection.insert_many([{'business_id': x, 'document_key': x, 'Existing': True} for x in range(10)])
df = pd.DataFrame([{'business_id': x, 'document_key': x, 'Updated': True} for x in range(3, 6)])

upserts = [
    UpdateOne(
        {'business_id': x['business_id'],
         "document_key": x["document_key"]},
        {'$set': x},
        upsert=True
    )
    for x in df.to_dict("records")
]

result = collection.bulk_write(upserts)

print(f'Matched: {result.matched_count}, Upserted: {result.upserted_count}, Modified: {result.modified_count}')

for document in collection.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    print(document)
```

prints:

```
Matched: 3, Upserted: 0, Modified: 3
{'business_id': 0, 'document_key': 0, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 1, 'document_key': 1, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 2, 'document_key': 2, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 3, 'document_key': 3, 'Existing': True, 'Updated': True}
{'business_id': 4, 'document_key': 4, 'Existing': True, 'Updated': True}
{'business_id': 5, 'document_key': 5, 'Existing': True, 'Updated': True}
{'business_id': 6, 'document_key': 6, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 7, 'document_key': 7, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 8, 'document_key': 8, 'Existing': True}
{'business_id': 9, 'document_key': 9, 'Existing': True}
```